# How to share variables between components (Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript, templates

I have two components and I am trying to export data (two variables), to the details component from login component. I have routing enabled. I does not seem to work. Where do I bind the variable? I want to show a details component on a new link where I can use these two variables.

login.component.ts

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  imgURL = "link";
  email = "email";
}
```

details.component.ts

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() imgURL;
  @Input() email;

}
```

details.component.html

```
<app-details [imgURL]="imgURL">
    {{imgURL}}

</app-details>
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <h2>Google Login</h2>
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col-md-4 mt-2 m-auto ">
            <button class="login-Btn" #loginRef>
              Login with Google<img class="social-btn-icon" alt="Login with Google" src="https://hrcdn.net/fcore/assets/google-colored-20b8216731.svg">
            </button>
            <a routerLink="/details" routerLinkActive="active">Details</a>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Check this or official document to learn more about Angular and data sharing techniques.https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/sharing-data-between-angular-components-f76fa680bf76

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can achieve this is to pass `imageUrl` and `email` as `queryParams` with the `routerLink` that navigates to the `details` component. You can then subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute's` `queryParams` observable on the `DetailsComponent` to get the variables.
On the `LoginComponent` template have this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/details']" [queryParams]="{ email: {{email}}, imgUrl: {{imgUrl}} }" routerLinkActive="active">Details</a>
```

Then on the `DetailsComponent` you can have this:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  imgUrl: string;
  email: string;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.email = params['email'];
      this.imgUrl = params['imgUrl'];
    });
  }
}
```